# eqal bottom margin between all floated divs

Tags: html, css

The snippet

```css
.card {
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.card:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class='card' style='height:50px;'>1</div>
<div class='card' style='height:20px;'>2</div>
<div class='card' style='height:30px;'>3</div>
<div class='card' style='height:20px;'>4</div>
<div class='card' style='height:250x;'>5</div>
<div class='card' style='height:35px;'>6</div>
<div class='card' style='height:50px;'>7</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/gfqf2LqL/)
You see that divs `1-4-7` don't have space between 10px. Is there a way to get equal vertical distance between all divs, without placing them in separate columns ?

Comment: Are the heights static ?

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph, no, heights are dynamic

Comment: You could check how masonry is made. I think this could be a solution for the problem you are facing .. http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Comment: Try implement it using flex (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @AlonEitan, I already tried various flex options - without success.

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no CSS solution...however, js/jquery solutions are possible (without masonry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made samples.

```css
.card {
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/*
this was not necessary...
.card:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
*/
.card:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(1)) {
  float: right;
}
.card:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

/* layout control */
.layout_control .card:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(1)) {
  margin-right: 6.5%;
}
```

```html
resolve only vertical margin
<div>
    <div class='card' style='height:50px;'>1</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:20px;'>2</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:30px;'>3</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:20px;'>4</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:250x;'>5</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:35px;'>6</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:50px;'>7</div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
<div>

adjust layout "margin-right: 6.5%"(need modifying value)
<div class="layout_control">
    <div class='card' style='height:50px;'>1</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:20px;'>2</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:30px;'>3</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:20px;'>4</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:250x;'>5</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:35px;'>6</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:50px;'>7</div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
<div>

NOT RESOLVED PATTERN
<div class="layout_control">
    <div class='card' style='height:50px;'>1</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:80px;'>2</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:30px;'>3</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:20px;'>4</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:250x;'>5</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:35px;'>6</div>
    <div class='card' style='height:50px;'>7</div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
<div>
```

Comment: hmm... you gave me an idea. Thanks a lot. Let's say - solved. Btw `.card:first-child` instead of `.cart:first-child` in your code.